# Is there a way to multiply two nested arrays by each other while maintaining O(n)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I want to multiply these two arrays. After I reduce any nested array with the product of its values.

```
[ [ 1 ], [ 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]

[ [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4 ], [ 1 ] ]
```

The answer should be:

```
[24, 12, 8, 6]
```

Clarification:

24 = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4

If there is any other approach please let me know. The code can't be of anything higher than O(n) and **no usage of division operator**.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about `big-o` complexity like `O(n)`, it's important to know what the `n` refers to. In case of a simple array it's typically the array size. In your case however, you have arrays of arrays so `n` can refer to the size of the inner or the outer array.

To simplify it, consider the outer array as containing `x` arrays and the inner arrays as having `y` elements. Then it require `2y-1` multiplications for each inner array. Since there are `x` inner arrays, it will in total require `x(2y-1)` multiplications. In big-o that would be O(xy).

So to answer your question.

If your `n` refers to either the number of inner arrays **or** the number of elements in the inner arrays then yes, it will be O(n).

However, if your `n` refers to both the inner and the outer dimension (i.e. both are growing at the same time) then no, it will be O(n^2).

In table form:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Outer dimension | Inner dimension | Complexity |
--------------------------------------------------
|    growing      |     constant    |   O(n)     |
--------------------------------------------------
|    constant     |     growing     |   O(n)     |
--------------------------------------------------
|    growing      |     growing     |   O(n^2)   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

And just to make clear: There is no magic that can turn the last case into O(n).

Comment: Where would `2y-1` arise?

Comment: @greybeard To multiply `y` elements you need `y-1` multiplications. Then you have 2 inner arrays so you get `2 * (y-1)` and then you need to multiply the two results, i.e. `2 * (y - 1) + 1` or just `2y - 1`

Comment: (You "omitted" the parentheses in the sentence with *each*.)